# Find the real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\log{(\frac{x^{2}+6x+9}{10})}=a\log{(x+3)}+b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I would like to know if what I'm doing is correct because I'm not sure.

Find the real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\log{(\frac{x^{2}+6x+9}{10})}=a\log{(x+3)}+b$.

For $b$,

$$\log{\left ( \frac{x^{2}+6x+9}{10} \right )}=a\log{(x+3)}+b$$

$$\log{\left ( \frac{(x+3)^{2}}{10} \right )}=a\log{(x+3)}+b$$

$$\log{\left ( (x+3)^{2} \right )}-\log{10}=a\log{(x+3)}+b$$

$$2\log{(x+3)}-1=a\log{(x+3)}+b$$

$$2\log{(x+3)}-a\log{(x+3)}-1=b$$

$$(2-a)\log{(x+3)}-1=b$$

Then for $a$,

$$\log{\left ( \frac{x^{2}+6x+9}{10} \right )}=a\log{(x+3)}+b$$

$$\log{\left (\frac{(x+3)^{2}}{10} \right )}=a\log{(x+3)}+b$$

$$\log{\left ( (x+3)^{2}\right )}-\log{10}=a\log{(x+3)}+b$$

$$2\log{(x+3)}-1=a\log{(x+3)}+b$$

$$2\log{(x+3)}-1-b=a\log{(x+3)}$$

$$\frac{2\log{(x+3)}-1-b}{\log{(x+3)}}=\frac{a\log{(x+3)}}{\log{(x+3)}}$$

$$\frac{2\log{(x+3)}-1-b}{\log{(x+3)}}=a$$

Comment: Once you get to $2\log(x+3)-1=a\log(x+3)+b$, can't you find values of $a$ and $b$ that work, just by looking at that equation?

Comment: precisely what I was thinking as well. Do you just need to find one pair (a, b) that works, or are you trying to describe all pairs (a, b) that could satisfy your equation?

Comment: @GerryMyerson hahhaha OMG! And I was overthinking this. So $a=2$ and $b=-1$?

Comment: Of course, all this assumes $x>-3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're sort of on the right track, but the problem you're encountering is that you've solved for $b$ in terms of $a$ and $x$, and then $a$ in terms of $b$ and $x$, but neither of these is sufficiently specific, because the given equation is supposed to hold true for all $x$ for which the expression is well-defined.

Suppose $$\log \frac{x^2 + 6x + 9}{10} = a \log (x+3) + b \tag{1}$$ is true for all $x > -3$.  (We added the condition $x > -3$ because otherwise the logarithm on the right hand side is not real-valued.)  Assuming that $\log$ represents the **common** (base-$10$) logarithm, then you concluded that $$(2-a)\log(x+3) = b+1. \tag{2}$$  If this equation $(2)$ is true for any $x  > -3$, we can see for example that the choice $x = -2$ would imply $b + 1 = 0$, hence $b = -1$ is the only solution for $b$ that could satisfy the condition for all such $x$; in turn, this implies $a = 2$.  Consequently, $(a,b) = (2,-1)$ is a solution to $(1)$ for all such $x$.

However, is this the only solution?  Perhaps we missed others?  To consider whether we did or not, we have to review the steps you took to get to Equation $(2)$; in particular, did any steps cause us to lose any solutions?  The only step that might have done this is when you wrote $$\log \frac{(x+3)^2}{10} = 2 \log (x+3) - \log 10.$$  This equation only holds true if $x > -3$, since the left-hand side is defined for all real $x$, not just $x > -3$; e.g., $$\log \frac{(-13 + 3)^2}{10} = \log \frac{(-10)^2}{10} = \log \frac{100}{10} = \log 10 = 1.$$  But because the original equation $(1)$ is only defined when $x > -3$, we see that there is no loss of generality, which completes our investigation, and confirms that $(a,b) = (2,-1)$ is the unique solution.